# daemonset doesn't create any pods

Tags: kubernetes

I'm trying to get going with Kubernetes DaemonSets and not having any luck at all. I've searched for a solution to no avail. I'm hoping someone here can help out.

First, I've seen [this ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34818198/daemonset-doesnt-create-any-pods-v1-1-2). Restarting the controller manager doesn't appear to help. As you can see here, the other kube processes have all been started after the apiserver and the api server has '--runtime-config=extensions/v1beta1=true' set.

```
kube     31398     1  0 08:54 ?        00:00:37 /usr/bin/kube-apiserver --logtostderr=true --v=0 --etcd_servers=http://dock-admin:2379 --address=0.0.0.0 --allow-privileged=false --portal_net=10.254.0.0/16 --admission_control=NamespaceAutoProvision,LimitRanger,ResourceQuota --runtime-config=extensions/v1beta1=true
kube     12976     1  0 09:49 ?        00:00:28 /usr/bin/kube-controller-manager --logtostderr=true --v=0 --master=http://127.0.0.1:8080 --cloud-provider=
kube     29489     1  0 11:34 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/kube-scheduler --logtostderr=true --v=0 --master=http://127.0.0.1:8080
```

However api-versions only shows version 1:

```
$ kubectl api-versions
Available Server Api Versions: v1
```

Kubernetes version is 1.2:

```
$ kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"2", GitVersion:"v1.2.0", GitCommit:"86327329213fed4af2661c5ae1e92f9956b24f55", GitTreeState:"clean"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"2", GitVersion:"v1.2.0", GitCommit:"86327329213fed4af2661c5ae1e92f9956b24f55", GitTreeState:"clean"}
```

The DaemonSet has been created, but appears to have no pods scheduled (status.desiredNumberScheduled).

```
$ kubectl get ds -o json
{
    "kind": "List",
    "apiVersion": "v1",
    "metadata": {},
    "items": [
        {
            "kind": "DaemonSet",
            "apiVersion": "extensions/v1beta1",
            "metadata": {
                "name": "ds-test",
                "namespace": "dvlp",
                "selfLink": "/apis/extensions/v1beta1/namespaces/dvlp/daemonsets/ds-test",
                "uid": "2d948b18-fa7b-11e5-8a55-00163e245587",
                "resourceVersion": "2657499",
                "generation": 1,
                "creationTimestamp": "2016-04-04T15:37:45Z",
                "labels": {
                    "app": "ds-test"
                }
            },
            "spec": {
                "selector": {
                    "app": "ds-test"
                },
                "template": {
                    "metadata": {
                        "creationTimestamp": null,
                        "labels": {
                            "app": "ds-test"
                        }
                    },
                    "spec": {
                        "containers": [
                            {
                                "name": "ds-test",
                                "image": "foo.vt.edu:1102/dbaa-app:v0.10-dvlp",
                                "ports": [
                                    {
                                        "containerPort": 8080,
                                        "protocol": "TCP"
                                    }
                                ],
                                "resources": {},
                                "terminationMessagePath": "/dev/termination-log",
                                "imagePullPolicy": "IfNotPresent"
                            }
                        ],
                        "restartPolicy": "Always",
                        "terminationGracePeriodSeconds": 30,
                        "dnsPolicy": "ClusterFirst",
                        "securityContext": {}
                    }
                }
            },
            "status": {
                "currentNumberScheduled": 0,
                "numberMisscheduled": 0,
                "desiredNumberScheduled": 0
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Here is my yaml file to create the DaemonSet

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: DaemonSet
metadata:
  name: ds-test
spec:
  selector:
    app: ds-test
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: ds-test
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: ds-test
        image: foo.vt.edu:1102/dbaa-app:v0.10-dvlp
        ports:
          - containerPort: 8080
```

Using that file to create the DaemonSet appears to work (I get 'daemonset "ds-test" created'), but no pods are created:

```
$ kubectl get pods -o json
{
    "kind": "List",
    "apiVersion": "v1",
    "metadata": {},
    "items": []
}
```

Comment: Can you run `kubectl describe ds ds-test` to find out more information about the daemonset you created? You may also want to check the kube-controller-manager log to see if (1) a daemon set controller was started at startup, (2) the `ds-test` was sync'd by the controller.

Comment: $ kubectl describe ds ds-test
Name:           ds-test
Image(s):       foo.vt.edu:1102/dbaa-app:v0.10-dvlp
Selector:       app=ds-test
Node-Selector:  <none>
Labels:         app=ds-test
Desired Number of Nodes Scheduled: 0
Current Number of Nodes Scheduled: 0
Number of Nodes Misscheduled: 0
Pods Status:    0 Running / 0 Waiting / 0 Succeeded / 0 Failed
No events.

Comment: How many nodes does your cluster have and what size? Do you have enough capacity on your cluster to place the pod?

Comment: We have two nodes in the cluster. But deleting all other pods doesn't seem to help. (I can start an RC just fine). So it's not a capacity problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

(I would have posted this as a comment, if I had enough reputation)

I am confused by your output.

`kubectl api-versions` should print out `extensions/v1beta1` if it is enabled on the server. Since it does not, it looks like extensions/v1beta1 is not enabled.

But `kubectl get ds` should fail if extensions/v1beta1 is not enabled. So I can not figure out if extensions/v1beta1 is enabled on your server or not.

Can you try GET `masterIP/apis` and see if extensions is listed there?
You can also go to `masterIP/apis/extensions/v1beta1` and see if daemonsets is listed there.

Also, I see `kubectl version` says 1.2, but then `kubectl api-versions` should not print out the string `Available Server Api Versions` (that string was removed in 1.1: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/15796).

Comment: $ curl http://localhost:8080/apis  
    {  
      "groups": [  
        {  
          "name": "extensions",  
          "versions": [  
            {  
              "groupVersion": "extensions/v1beta1",  
              "version": "v1beta1"  
            }  
          ],  
          "preferredVersion": {  
            "groupVersion": "extensions/v1beta1",  
            "version": "v1beta1"  
          }  
        }  
      ]

Comment: `curl http://localhost:8080/apis`  reports that extensions/v1beta1 is installed. `curl http://localhost:8080/apis/extensions/v1beta1` reports that daemonsets is available.

Comment: Awesome! that means apiserver is fine. Lets look at controller manager. Do you see "Starting daemon set controller" in controller manager logs (`/var/log/kube-controller-manager.log`)? Are any other controllers started? (for example: look for "Starting ReplicaSet controller" to see if replica set controller is started).

Comment: We do not see that in the log. Restarting kubernetes logs the restart, but no "Starting * controller"

Comment: We do see: dock-admin kube-controller-manager: E0408 10:50:13.582477   19001 controllermanager.go:277] Failed to start service controller: ServiceController should not be run without a cloudprovider

Comment: That seems like a problem with cluster setup. Since no controller starts, ReplicationController should not be working in your cluster either.  Can you share details about your environment and commands you are using to bring up the cluster? Are you using one of the official guides (from http://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/)?

Comment: I was thinking the same thing. We're going to re-provision and give it another go.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

I have this issue in my cluster (k8s version: 1.9.7):

[image]

Daemonset controlled by "Daemonset controller" not "Scheduler", So I restart the `controller manager`, the problem sloved:

[image]

But I think this is a issue of kubernetes, some relation info:

[Bug 1469037 - Sometime daemonset DESIRED=0 even this matched node](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1469037)

[v1.7.4 - Daemonset DESIRED 0 (for node-exporter) #51785](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/51785)

Answer (score 1):

I was facing a similar issue, then tried searching for the daemonset in the kube-system namespace, as mentioned here, https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/61342
I actually did get an output properly as well

Answer (score 0):

**For any case that the current state of pods is not equal to desired state** (whether it was created by a DaemonSet, ReplicaSet, Deployment etc') **I would first check the Kubelet** on the current node:

```
$ sudo systemctl status kubelet
```

Or:

```
$ sudo journalctl -u kubelet
```

In many cases pods weren't created in my cluster because of errors like:

```
Couldn't parse as pod (Object 'Kind' is missing in 'null')
```

Which [might occur](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/40452) after editing a resource's yaml in editor like vim.

Answer (score -4):

Try:

$kubectl taint nodes --all node-role.kubernetes.io/master:NoSchedule-

master node cannot accept pods.