# fluentd-es-v1.22 DaemonSet doesn't create any pod

Tags: kubernetes, coreos, fluentd

I went through both [daemonset doesn't create any pods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36407449/daemonset-doesnt-create-any-pods) and [DaemonSet doesn't create any pods: v1.1.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34818198/daemonset-doesnt-create-any-pods-v1-1-2) before asking this question. Here is my problem.

Kubernetes cluster is running on CoreOS

```
NAME=CoreOS
ID=coreos
VERSION=1185.3.0
VERSION_ID=1185.3.0
BUILD_ID=2016-11-01-0605
PRETTY_NAME="CoreOS 1185.3.0 (MoreOS)"
ANSI_COLOR="1;32"
HOME_URL="https://coreos.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://github.com/coreos/bugs/issues"
```

I refer to https://coreos.com/kubernetes/docs/latest/getting-started.html guide and created 3 etcd, 2 masters and 42 nodes. All applications running in the cluster without issue.

I got a requirement of setting up logging with fluentd-elasticsearch and downloaded yaml files in  https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/tree/master/cluster/addons/fluentd-elasticsearch deployed fluentd deamonset.

```
kubectl create -f fluentd-es-ds.yaml
```

I could see it got created but none of pod created.

```
kubectl --namespace=kube-system get ds -o wide
NAME               DESIRED   CURRENT   NODE-SELECTOR                               AGE       CONTAINER(S)   IMAGE(S)                                              SELECTOR
fluentd-es-v1.22   0         0         alpha.kubernetes.io/fluentd-ds-ready=true   4h        fluentd-es     gcr.io/google_containers/fluentd-elasticsearch:1.22   k8s-app=fluentd-es,kubernetes.io/cluster-service=true,version=v1.22

kubectl --namespace=kube-system describe ds fluentd-es-v1.22
Name:           fluentd-es-v1.22
Image(s):       gcr.io/google_containers/fluentd-elasticsearch:1.22
Selector:       k8s-app=fluentd-es,kubernetes.io/cluster-service=true,version=v1.22
Node-Selector:  alpha.kubernetes.io/fluentd-ds-ready=true
Labels:         k8s-app=fluentd-es
                kubernetes.io/cluster-service=true
                version=v1.22
Desired Number of Nodes Scheduled: 0
Current Number of Nodes Scheduled: 0
Number of Nodes Misscheduled: 0
Pods Status:    0 Running / 0 Waiting / 0 Succeeded / 0 Failed
No events.
```

I verified below details according to the comments in above SO questions.

```
kubectl api-versions
apps/v1alpha1
authentication.k8s.io/v1beta1
authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
autoscaling/v1
batch/v1
batch/v2alpha1
certificates.k8s.io/v1alpha1
extensions/v1beta1
policy/v1alpha1
rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1alpha1
storage.k8s.io/v1beta1
v1
```

I could see below logs in one kube-controller-manager after restart.

```
I0116 20:48:25.367335       1 controllermanager.go:326] Starting extensions/v1beta1 apis
I0116 20:48:25.367368       1 controllermanager.go:328] Starting horizontal pod controller.
I0116 20:48:25.367795       1 controllermanager.go:343] Starting daemon set controller
I0116 20:48:25.367969       1 horizontal.go:127] Starting HPA Controller
I0116 20:48:25.369795       1 controllermanager.go:350] Starting job controller
I0116 20:48:25.370106       1 daemoncontroller.go:236] Starting Daemon Sets controller manager
I0116 20:48:25.371637       1 controllermanager.go:357] Starting deployment controller
I0116 20:48:25.374243       1 controllermanager.go:364] Starting ReplicaSet controller
```

The other one has below log.

```
I0116 23:16:23.033707       1 leaderelection.go:295] lock is held by {master.host.name} and has not yet expired
```

Am I missing something? Appreciate your help on figure out the issue.

Answer (score 4):

I found the solution after studying https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/cluster/addons/fluentd-elasticsearch/fluentd-es-ds.yaml

There is `nodeSelector: set as alpha.kubernetes.io/fluentd-ds-ready: "true"`

But nodes doesn't have a label like that. What I did is add the label as below to one node to check whether it's working.

```
kubectl label nodes {node_name} alpha.kubernetes.io/fluentd-ds-ready="true"
```

After that, I could see fluentd pod started to run

```
kubectl --namespace=kube-system get pods
NAME                                   READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
fluentd-es-v1.22-x1rid                 1/1       Running   0          6m
```

Thanks.